# Docker do not link virtual interfaces to virtual network(bridge)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bridge, arch

When create and start my all instances everything looks fine but even though do routing  properly, my instances still cannot communicate each others. I have use this this command for each instance.

`ip link set <interface> master <network>`
eg
`ip link set vethb3735ba@if14 master br-bdf6dd295e3a`

Here is my operation system details

Linux arch 6.0.2-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat, 15 Oct 2022 14:00:49 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```yaml
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: amigoscode
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 200M
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 200M
  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    container_name: zipkin
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"
    networks:
      - spring
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 200M

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9.11-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - spring
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 200M

  eureka-server:
    image: huseyinafsin/eureka-server:latest
    container_name: eureka-server
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 200M

  apigw:
    image: huseyinafsin/apigw:latest
    container_name: apigw
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 200M

  customer:
    image: huseyinafsin/customer:latest
    container_name: customer
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
      - eureka-server
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 200M

  fraud:
    image: huseyinafsin/fraud:latest
    container_name: fraud
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
      - eureka-server
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 200M

  notification:
    image: huseyinafsin/notification:latest
    container_name: notification
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
      - eureka-server
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 200M

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
  spring:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

Comment: The question you're asking doesn't really seem like a programming-related question.  I can at least say that you shouldn't need low-level network-setup commands like `ip` just to run a container, Docker manages that for you.

Comment: @DavidMaze I searched for a solution for almost a week but this is only solution to made them talk. I don't care if my system down btw 

Comment: You should be able to use the Compose service names `fraud`, `notification`, and so on as host names, without doing any special setup.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: I have read that doc before, I think it't this issue not relating docker it self. Probably network manager is causing